# Should I use check or checked?

Tags: naming

I'm designing a library that binds to html elements on a page. In this particular case the input[type='checkbox'] will be checked if the likeItem property returns true and unchecked if the likeItem property returns false. What's the best practice for naming properties?

input { check: likeItem }

or

input { checked: likeItem }

This would also apply to other things like enable/enabled, disable/disabled, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For semantic reasons and best practice use `checked`.

`input { checked: isTrue }` will be processed after the input is checked. So, for me, I think `checked` get better this context.

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on what you do if the property returns `false`. If the input happens to be checked, and you send `input { checked: isFalse }`, I would expect that the library will uncheck the checkbox - set it's `checked` property to `false`(even though the `checked` attribute in HTML doesn't uses present/absent and not `true`/`false`).

But if the input is checked, and you send `input { check: isFalse }`, I would expect that the library will **not** uncheck the checkbox, and that it'll remain checked! `check` is a verb, which means an action, so `{ check: isFalse }` means either "call `check` with `false`"(which I don't think is the case here, since a function named `check` should not accept a boolean argument - if it does it should have been named `setChecked` or something) or "don't call `check`". So if the checkbox is unchecked sending `{ check: isFalse }` will do nothing and the checkbox will remain unchecked, and if the checkbox is checked it'll still do nothing and the checkbox will remain checked. If you want to uncheck you should send `input { uncheck: isTrue }`.